# Copy and pasting data into different worksheet-Lookup intersection

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am trying to build a macro which basically copies and pastes data from `worksheet("sheet2")` to `worksheet("sheet3")`.

In **sheet 2** i have Dates in column A `cells(2,1).End(xlUp).Row`. Below i have taken a snap shot off my data.

I have both the value of the USD and EUR for each field. The last column used is usually unknown this will vary.

[image]

In **sheet 3** were i want to that data to be pasted to, i want the macro to look up the dates from sheet2 and if found paste the data.The dates to be looked up are in **column D.** row 2.

The **tricky part** is that USD values should pasted in column **I to K** and pasted again in column **L to N**. The EUR values should be pasted between column **O to  Q**. Then in column **R to T** USD values pasted into here as well. The column headers in sheet 3 are the same as sheet 2.

I had tried a vlookup, but realised that this will not the most efficient approach to this.

**Result on Sheet 3**

Only information being copied over is the values. The dates are already in sheet 3. 
ie if date is found in sheet 3, the amounts will be populated in the right column.  No new line will be created.

In the sections of the USD values

[image]

In the EUR section the  result will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: @Jarom i had tried a vlookup , but would have meant this being set up in each cell.

Comment: James, it's not clear to me how you would copy data to the sheet 3. Did you mean same values from column `D` several times over in the column? Or that you'd copy column `B` to `G` and do conversion between USD/EUR?

Comment: @Jarom same values Will be copied several times over

Comment: @james. Do a mock up of sheet 3 so we can see what ends up on sheet three from sheet2 and why ... It appears the same values of USD get copied from column C or E on sheet 2 to I-N O-T and AA-FF on sheet 3 ??

Comment: @perfo see in question i have added

Comment: @perfo I amended the ranges for better understanding of the example.

Comment: The key to your plan is in matching the dates in both sheets. Therefore you should give more information about these. Are dates in sequence in both sheets? Do they cover the same period? Are there dates missing (or extra dates) between the sheets? Does one of the sheets have the same date more than once? Are the dates true dates (numbers) or "fake" dates (strings) in either of the sheets?

Comment: @Variatus the dates in both are the same.  There are no dates missing. The dates are not always in sequence. These are both formatted as dates in both sheets

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyIt()
  Dim CheckDate As Date
  Dim FoundRow As Integer
  Dim Range_T0_Search As String

  '** get the date you are looking for from sheet 3 cell D2 ***
  CheckDate = Sheet3.Range("D2").Value

  '****
  Range_T0_Search = "A2:A" & Trim(Str(Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row))
  FoundRow = findIt(Range_T0_Search, CheckDate)


     '*** if it can't find the date on sheet2 then don't copy anything
  If FoundRow = 0 Then Exit Sub

  '*** do the USD bit *****
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 1) = CheckDate '** put the date on sheet 3 ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 3) '*** copy across usd income ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 5) '*** copy across usd Expensies ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 7) '*** copy across usd Tax ***

  '*** Do the Euro bit ****
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 7) = CheckDate '** put the date on sheet 3 ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 8) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 2) '*** copy across usd income ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 9) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 4) '*** copy across usd Expensies ***
  Sheet3.Cells(6, 10) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 6) '*** copy across usd Tax ***


End Sub

Function findIt(Dates_Range As String, Date_To_Find As Date) As Integer
  Dim C As Variant
  Dim Address As Range

  With Sheet2.Range(Dates_Range)
    Set C = .Find(Date_To_Find, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        findIt = Range(C.Address).Row
    End If
End With

End Function
```

The above does what I think you want bar the actual formatting and columns you want. 
It takes a date from cell D2 on sheet three.  It looks for that date on Sheet 2 in column A. If it finds it, it will copy across the data. First a group of USD data then euros. You will have to change it to put the data in the columns you want but I hope it gets you on the right track.

Comment: thanks for the above. i have amended the code slightly as i do not need to dates to be copied over. How can get  the macro to paste the data on the same column as the dates already there in sheet 3?

Comment: So you have a list of dates on sheet3? you state above "The dates to be looked up are in column D. row 2." this means the date is in cell D2. If there is a list of dates say in column A on sheet3 then the following should do it..

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyIt()
  Dim CheckDate As Date
  Dim FoundRow As Integer
  Dim Range_T0_Search As String
  Dim Rownum As Integer

  '*** Go through each date on sheet 3 column A in turn and try to find it on sheet 2 ****
  For Rownum = 2 To Sheet3.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    '** get the date you are looking for from sheet 3 Coumn A ***
    CheckDate = Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 1).Value

    '**** set the range where you wnat to look for the date containe din checkdate ****
    Range_T0_Search = "A2:A" & Trim(Str(Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row))
    FoundRow = findIt(Range_T0_Search, CheckDate)

    '*** if it can't find the date on sheet2 then don't copy anything
    If FoundRow = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '*** do the USD bit *****

    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 3) '*** copy across usd income ***
    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 5) '*** copy across usd Expensies ***
    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 7) '*** copy across usd Tax ***

    '*** Do the Euro bit ****

    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 8) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 2) '*** copy across usd income ***
    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 9) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 4) '*** copy across usd Expensies ***
    Sheet3.Cells(Rownum, 10) = Sheet2.Cells(FoundRow, 6) '*** copy across usd Tax ***
 Next

End Sub

Function findIt(Dates_Range As String, Date_To_Find As Date) As Integer
  Dim C As Variant
  Dim Address As Range

  With Sheet2.Range(Dates_Range)
    Set C = .Find(Date_To_Find, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        findIt = Range(C.Address).Row
    End If
End With

End Function
```